# FPPickerControllerKey only shows up for certain sources

Tags: ios, cordova, filepicker.io

Using the inkfilepicker library on the iPad Simulator, when uploading from the **source "Albums"** I end up with the following result:

```
{"FPPickerControllerFilename": "...03.JPG",
"FPPickerControllerMediaURL":"file://localhost/Users/.../...Pmr",
"FPPickerControllerKey":"YqW..._...03.JPG",
"result":"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo",
"FPPickerControllerMediaType":"public.image",
"FPPickerControllerRemoteURL":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/eI...0H"}
```

When I choose a **different source**, like facebook, the FPPickerControllerKey is missing. The images themselves are being uploaded to the S3 bucket correctly no matter what source. Is this a known issue? Could I be doing something wrong?

I am using the Cordova-Filepicker library (see link below) with the inkfilepicker ios library updated to the one from the ios docs under developers.inkfilepicker. I am checking for the values here: https://github.com/albertut/cordova-filepicker/blob/master/src/ios/CDVFilepicker.m#L167-176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by the inkfilepicker team. After my support case they fixed the issue on their server - all sources now return the S3 key (filename on S3). Yay!